# How do I shrink an image above some text depending on the amount of text?

Tags: html, css

I have images that I want displayed above some text.  The text could be very long or very short.  In every case, I want the text to stick to the bottom of my container and the image above it to shrink when necessary so that both items always fit in 100% of the container height.  The image can shrink to be very small if necessary, but I do not want it to stretch beyond its natural 100% width or height.

I've gotten close to the behavior I want using `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` but this only ensures the text starts in the desired position and does not resize the image above it.  How can I achieve this?

```css
#container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}
div.image-content img {
  /* how to force vertical resize? */
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
div.copy-content {
  /*this fixes the text but the image does not resize */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <!--image-->
  <div class="image-content">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cFypFxX.jpg" alt="Cat">
  </div>

  <!--text-->
  <div class="copy-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
      porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh.
      Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris
      ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** Here I have gotten close by using a background image strategy, but the problem is that I do not want my image to stretch beyond its natural 100% width or height if the container does.  `background-size: contain;` is what I want when the image must shrink, and `background-size: auto` is what I want when the container is bigger than the image:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
div.image-content {
  background: url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=300%C3%97150&w=300&h=150);
  
  /* desired behavior when div is LESS THAN image height */
  background-size: contain; 
  
  /* desired behavior when div is GREATER THAN image height */
  /*background-size: auto; */
  
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
div.copy-content {}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <!--image-->
  <div class="image-content">
    <!-- <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cFypFxX.jpg" alt="Cat"> -->
  </div>

  <!--text-->
  <div class="copy-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
      porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh.
      Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris
      ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt
      mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna
      luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia
      Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec.d</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, since the SO snippets don't seem to let you resize the output window, here is a jsFiddle: [same snippet in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andyraddatz/Lw9c45sw/7/)

Comment: So you want a img behave like a background image ?

Comment: You want your text below of your image right, that can be achieved if you remove position absolute and assign height, width to both imgdiv and contentdiv.

Comment: @DaniP Thanks for the comment, I did some testing with a background image and it behaved perfectly EXCEPT that I couldn't stop the image growth at the image's natural 100% width/height.  I will update the question with that requirement.

Comment: @frnt Yes I could do that with explicit height/width, but I do not know the incoming sizes of the images or text.  I want it to be dynamic so that the container will show all text at the bottom and shrink any image size above it as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

With a mixture of `inline-block` elements, absolute positioning and a spacer hack, you should be able to achieve this with css

```css
/* make container as big as it's content */

.container,
.copy-content,
.copy-content p {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.spacer {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 50%;  /* this is specific to the image - worked out by height / width and keeps the spacer in ratio with the image */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="spacer"></span>

  <!--image-->
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=300%C3%97150&w=300&h=150" alt="sports" class="image">

  <!--text-->
  <div class="copy-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
      porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh.
      Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris
      ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>


<div class="container">
  <span class="spacer"></span>

  <!--image-->
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=300%C3%97150&w=300&h=150" alt="sports" class="image">

  <!--text-->
  <div class="copy-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>


<div class="container">
  <span class="spacer"></span>

  <!--image-->
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=300%C3%97150&w=300&h=150" alt="sports" class="image">

  <!--text-->
  <div class="copy-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor. Sed convallis tristique sem.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to, you can make the image as a background image on the spacer instead of absolutely positioning it

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is slightly different than what I am looking for.  As you say in your comment, this will: `/* make container as big as it's content */` but what I want is to make my _content_ (img + text) be as short as my _container_ needs to fit both inside of its full height (with no vertical overflow).